# Is my code a proper way to handle NodeJS mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am wondering if this is a proper way to handle my mysql queries? Should I be checking if the pool was already created like below, is it bad to call createPool many times?

Thanks

```
module.exports.pool = function(callback) {
    let mysql = require('mysql');
    let pool;
    if (pool) { } else {
        pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: ""
        });
        console.log ("Pool created!")
    };

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        callback(err, connection);
        connection.release();
    });
};
```

Comment: Use existing package instead you create your own
https://sequelize.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

You create a function that returns the pool:

```
let pool = undefined

module.exports = function getPool() {
  if (pool) return pool;
  pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: ""
  });
  return pool;
}
```

This encapsulates the concern and isolates it from the rest of the application.